# How do i insert a date from c#?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, informix

I have this insert:

```
insert into sap_paghe (nome_elaborazione, data_elaborazione, tipo, data_registrazione, data_scadenza, data_documento, osservazioni, data_allocazione_iva) values ('Nome elaborazione', '2021-12-22', 'H', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', 'RETRIBUZIONI GEN. 2021', '2021-01-31');
```

which perfectly works from SQLWorkbench but gives this error using C#

```
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Invalid year in date
```

I'm 100% sure the connection works  because other inserts work fine, it's just the ones with the date. Any suggestion?

Here's the code:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(insert..., DbConnection);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand = command;
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Dispose();
```

Comment: Please show how you execute the query from C#

Comment: The dates in the `insert` are all correctly formatted and don't have any invalid years. I'd double check the number and types of columns. Perhaps the columns don't line up in your inserts.

Comment: Use proper parameters

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i just needed to put `TO_DATE('2021-01-31','%Y-%m-%d')` instead of just the date

Comment: The Informix DBDATE environment variable defaults to `MDY4/`, and controls the format expected for dates.  I run with `DBDATE='Y4MD-'` which makes ISO standard (ISO 8601, ISO 9075) date formats work.  There are a few related variables (`GL_DATE`, …) that you could play with too but probably shouldn't.  Your workaround deals with the problem at the cost of changing the SQL code.  Setting DBDATE (which is trivial in a Unix environment; I'm not so sure about the world of C# and Windows) is simpler in that it doesn't require code changes, but ensuring the environment is set correctly is a problem.